# How to correctly reference a supervisor who in the meantime got a doctorate

Tags: cv, citation-style

I completed one of my theses under the co-supervision of a (back then) PhD student. Said person has since completed his degree and is now officially "Dr. supervisor".

Since I want to reference his supervision in my CV, I was wondering whether I use the formal title that he holds now, or whether I reference him without a PhD, which was his status *during* the supervision?

I am pretty sure that this is more a non-issue for my specific case, but I can see this being a more common problem elsewhere, especially when listing references online.

Comment: I would not reference this person in my CV at all (unless they are particularly well-known). Your official thesis advisor was probably the boss of that PhD student (usually a professor). That person would be (somewhat) well-known and belongs in your CV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. FYI: I did not reference the name of my <s>supervisor</s> advisor at all in my industry-targeting resume.  I do realize this may be different in CV-land.
2. I personally wouldn't use any honorifics in the CV.  (Next you'll be asking about assistant versus full professor!)  Just convey the information, the name.  I would opt for FI, LN.  I.e. Advisor: D. Linger.  Keep it tight, man.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is Germany, where titles are a serious business, you might consider doing both.

... Herr Somebody (now Doktor Somebody).

It is partly for identification, I think, and the current title might be helpful.

Comment: There is no downside to using both titles as @Buffy recommends. If Doktor Somebody wishes to be known by everyone as Fritz, that is no business of yours in your CV, which should be all about you not about your advisor's precise titles.